# Java GUI using one Jtextfield for both text and number inputs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, jframe

I have a DAO class with some methods such as getting employees by ID and by name from a database. The methods are working correctly.

Now I decided to create a simple form with IntelliJ IDEA's GUI Designer. I want to be able to enter either an ID (int value) or a name (String value) into the same JtextField and to get the result shown after clicking the "Submit" button. Is it possible or should I just create additional JTextField and JButton pairs for each type of input?

For now I could make actionPerformed method work correctly only for methods searchEmployees (by name) and getAllEmployees (it just makes "SELECT * FROM employees" if a user clicks the JButton with the empty JTextField).
I'm new to building GUI apps so all suggestions for improving the code are welcome.

Here is my code

```
public class EmployeeApp extends JFrame {
private JPanel panelMain;
private JButton searchButton;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTextField idTextField;
private JLabel lastNameLabel;

private EmployeesDao employeesDao;


public EmployeeApp() {

    // create the DAO
    try {
        employeesDao = new EmployeesDao();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                String searchValue = idTextField.getText();

                List<Employee> employees;

                if (searchValue != null && searchValue.trim().length() > 0) {
                    employees = employeesDao.searchEmployees(searchValue);
                } else {
                    employees = employeesDao.getAllEmployees();
                }
                for (Employee temp : employees) {
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }

            } catch (Exception exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeApp.this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("EmployeeApp");
    frame.setContentPane(new EmployeeApp().panelMain);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

**Edit:**
I tried to modify the try/catch block and now when I enter a number into the JTextField the getEmployeeById method works correctly instead. However when entering a string I'm getting a NumberFormatException.

```
        searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String searchValue = idTextField.getText();
            List<Employee> employees;
            Employee employee;

            try {
                int numValue = Integer.parseInt(searchValue);
                employee = employeesDao.getEmployeeById(numValue);
                System.out.println(employee);

                if (searchValue != null && searchValue.trim().length() > 0) {
                    employees = employeesDao.searchEmployees(searchValue);
                }

                else {
                    employees = employeesDao.getAllEmployees();
                }
                for (Employee temp : employees) {
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }

            } catch (Exception exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeApp.this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not simply check the text entered. If it's numeric, then go for the id, and if not, then go for the name. This seems simple -- am I missing something and over-simplifying your problem?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm new to it so this may be my fault. I have a method getEmployeeById(int employeeId) and it returns Employee object, not a List<Employees> like other methods. So I want to figure out how it may also be handled with the addActionListener.

Comment: Return a `List<Employee>` for both, but for the integer fetch, it only contains one entry?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Employee Id is a primary key in my db table. So for one id only one employee may be returned.

Comment: So what? If the value is numeric, call getEmployeeById(), and then use `employees = Collections.singletonList(theFoundEmployee);`. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: So what? If the value is numeric, call getEmployeeById(), and then use `employees = Collections.singletonList(theFoundEmployee);`. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: @JBNizet see the edit. The JTextField doesn't accept both numbers and strings. I can't make both methods (getEmployeeById and searchEmployees) work. When I ented an Id in the text field it returns an employee by Id correctly. But if then I enter a name I get NumberFormatException for input string.

Comment: Integer.parseInt() throws a NumberFormatException if the string doesn't represent a valid int. Catch that exception. If caught, it means the string is not an integer, and you should then not treat is as such, and do a search instead of finding by ID.

Comment: I can't figure out how to proceed to the next method that takes another input. When a NumberFormatException is handled I have a pop up window with this info. But it's not like I can enter a number and it searches by Id and when I enter a string it searches for a name withiut interruptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we're suggesting is that you get the error message out of the catch block and instead do something more useful there. If the catch block is entered, then you know that the idTextField does not hold valid numeric data, and you should use the text to extract your data using name or text data, not numeric data. Something like:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String idText = idTextField.getText().trim();
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(idText);

            // if we have reached this line, then idText is numeric

            // code here to get Employee by value number

        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

            // don't show an error message here!
            // If we get here we know that idText is **not** numeric

            // code here to to get Employee by name using idText
        }
    }
```

But myself, I don't like this kind of kludgery and instead would try to make my code more idiot-proof. You could use JRadioButtons to allow the user to do data extraction with text or with numeric and then rig the JTextField so that it won't accept text if the user selects the numeric option. This can be done by setting and removing a DocumentFilter on the JTextField's Document for instance.

Comment: Thank you!! Your suggestion and code example helped me to understand what I was missing. Now I've got my code working correctly.)